# file:// protocol not working under ssl?

Tags: html, browser, ssl, hyperlink

I have a link to a shared mapped drive and I can confirm that the link is good, but the browser's ignoring the click.  Can someone confirm that browsers ignore `file:///` href's when they appear on a secure page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is that it's explicitly being denied.  The rule is: no access to resources via file:// from a page received via http[s]://.  It's a separation of security realms.  It's also more clearly defined by a [mozilla plugin](http://locallink.mozdev.org/).

Answer (score 1):

The file:// pseudo-protocol is for system-dependent access to files on a local system. It has nothing to do with SSL.

Comment: Yes, I understand that; I was wondering if a page received securely would setup a security context within the browser that would require it to ignore local file links.

Comment: @end-user, SSL is about encrypted and/or signed transfer over HTTP. It would be odd if it affected anything else. As you are requesting for confirmation, I think you should have given an example and identified browser(s) in which you have observed such behavior. Then again, file:// links in a page served with SSL sound very odd.

Comment: Alas, I cannot give an example because the page I'm working with is behind a firewall.  It's not really odd: as you point out, file:// on an ssl page *is* odd.  My use case is just that, a file:// link on a page served with the HTTPS protocol.  Would that create a context in the browser where it would refuse to enable such links?  As I said, I've tested the URL in question; pasting it into a location bar in FF, IE or Chrome successfully pulls the file.  However, none of them will connect when the link is clicked.

Comment: @end-user A file:// link on *any* page is odd, unless all browser users have identical file systems. It serves a local file at the client, not a file at the server.

Comment: So, for example, a page on an intranet site that employees might access?  Perhaps a link to a standard mapped drive?  It's really not that unreasonable.